Group permission on a folder
I need to set a directory in which each member of the group can read/write/execute the scripts/file created by other member of the group.

I set my folder like this (getfacl results):
# file: dir/
# owner: root
# group: groupname
user::rwx
user:user1:rwx
user:user2:rwx
user:user3:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r--

but still when I create a new file as user1 in the folder this file is not executable from the group:
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 groupname 3021 ott 25 10:16 script.sh


I've tried also setting s permission to group, but is the same.

How can I solve it?

Just wondering,  did you run  chmod g+s /path/to/directory  then followed by the setfacl command?   And what was your sefacl command you executed?  setfacl -d -m group::rwx /path/to/directory  should work, combined with the chmod above

You are confusing the permissions on the directory with the permissions on the file.

@LjmDullaart so how can I set the permission on file?

@ValentinBajrami yes I run chmod..

Does chmod 770 script.sh not work?

you sample file is not executable by anyone, you need to chmod +x it. did you  a) copy it from another file b) original file has +x bit set ?

This question is similar to: facl ignoring the "x" permission but only on files. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
